# How to find the mean of a variable for every value of another variable?

Tags: r, subset, mean

I'm new here, so pardon such a basic question, but I just started R and I've been asked a question that's left me stumped:

Using the pre-installed dataset in R, mtcars, I'm supposed to find the mean of the "mpg" variable for each value of the "gear" variable. I'm not exactly sure what this means. I assume I need to use subsetting?

It's so basic so I'm a little frustrated I'm not seeing what to do here....

Comment: You might try going through the tutorial here: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame `mtcars` is an object that has rows and columns. I've not seen the entire dataset, but `mpg` is a column on that dataset and I'd guess that `gear` is also a column on the dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(mtcars$mpg,list(mtcars$gear),mean)
##  Group.1        x
##1       3 16.10667
##2       4 24.53333
##3       5 21.38000
```

According to the documentation, see `?aggregate`:

> Splits the data into subsets, computes summary statistics for each, and returns the result in a convenient form.

Here, the first argument `mtcars$mpg` is the variable you want to average, and the second argument is a list of grouping variables by which each of its value determines the subset of `x` to apply the function, `mean`, that is the third argument.

Comment: good answer, but it might be a little cleaner with the formula interface `aggregate(mpg ~ gear, mtcars, mean)`.

Comment: One of the frustrating things about the coding classes here, is that they teach us the very basics and ask us questions that concern code we haven't gone over yet. Thanks for introducing me to the aggregate function! Big help!

Answer (score 3):

Or use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(avg_mpg = mean(mpg)), by = gear]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's useful to start by visualizing the data:

```
plot(x = mtcars$gear, y = mtcars$mpg)
```

[image]

We can see that `gear` takes 3 values (3, 4, and 5), and we wish to find the average `mpg` value for each value of gear.

We can do this via subsetting, as you suggest:

```
mean(subset(mtcars, gear == 3)$mpg)
# [1] 16.10667
```

But a way to do it using `base` R functions is `tapply`:

```
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear, mean)
#        3        4        5 
# 16.10667 24.53333 21.38000
```